# Move DependencyObject between threads

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety

I perform a lengthy operation (connection test, validation of remote DB tables, etc.) in a separate thread in a WPF app. During the testing, I collect information for the user about which tests were passed and which weren't. The information is stored as a `List<T>` of objects of my own design:

```
public class StatusItem : DependencyObject
{
    public string Text { get... set... }
    public Status Status { get... set... }
    public string Details { get... set... }
}
```

All these properties are a front for their corresponding `DependencyProperty`. When the operation is completed (in the separate thread), I set the collected info, `status`, to a private field on my `Window`. I get a:

```
InvalidOperationException:
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Is there a way for me to transfer `status` (a `List<StatusItem>`) from TestThread to my main thread without having to resort to delegates and `Dispatcher` invokes?

PS: I could do `Invoke`, but I'd rather avoid having to create a `CopyStatusItemsDelegate` delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a nice solution. The above situation is the reason, why I don't derive Item-ViewModels from `DependencyObject` but implement `INotifiyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @svick, PropertyChanged notifications from `INotifyPropertyChanged` are not thread agnostic. They are delegated to the UI thread even if raised from another thread.

Comment: @svick: As I wrote already on your comment to invisible, I think you're wrong. As long as it is not a collection change, binding will accept cross thread calls.

Comment: @HCL, I must've confused that with the collection change.

Comment: After some pondering, I've realised that I don't need `DependencyObject`. I've implemented with the `INPC` interface instead. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

About DependencyObject from msdn:

> This object can be accessed only from the thread on which it was
>   created. Attempts to access it from other threads will throw an
>   InvalidOperationException. Invoke or BeginInvoke provide support for
>   marshalling work to the correct thread.

If you must have DependencyObject in your case, so use Invoke. Otherwise, I suggest you to use INotifyPropertyChanged interface implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following hack if you have full trust:

```
public static class DispatcherExtenstions {
    public static void SetAccess(this DispatcherObject d) {
        if(d.CheckAccess()) return;
        Dispatcher dispatcher = d.Dispatcher;
        FieldInfo dispatcherThreadField = typeof(Dispatcher).GetField("_dispatcherThread", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        dispatcherThreadField.SetValue(dispatcher, Thread.CurrentThread);
}
}
```

Sample:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    Button b;
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread t = new Thread(CreateButton);
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }
    void CreateButton() {
        b = new Button() { Padding = new Thickness(20.0) };
        b.Content = new Button { Content = "Button" };
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)ShowButton);
    }
    void ShowButton() {
        b.SetAccess();
        Content = b;
    }
}
```